# NextJS: Is there a way to invoke something only on serverside, only on a fresh page load?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

Our team initially created an `_app.tsx` with `getInitialProps`, and included something along the lines of

```
if (!req) return {};
```

as the top line. The idea was to make `getInitialProps` run only on the server side, only on initial page load. We thought it was a safe assumption as the usual advice (often repeated in stackoverflow answers) is that `getInitialProps` runs client-side on page transitions.

We later discovered that `getInitialProps` actually runs server-side on page transitions, if you are transitioning to a page that has `getServerSideProps`.

So that doesn't serve our purposes - we have several network queries that are made in `getInitialProps` that are being made on most of our page transitions (since most of our pages have `getServerSideProps`), when our intention was to only run those queries on a fresh page (app) load.

We could instead use `useEffect` only on component mount, but we want to run those queries serverside instead of client side, to protect against visual flashes.

I'm learning how to set up a context, with a setState inside, but initial testing shows that its initial setState runs on both clientside and serverside:

```
...

const getString = (): string => {
  console.log('about to set string!');
  return 'string';
};

const PagePropsProvider: React.FC<IProps> = ({ pageProps, children }) => {
  const [sample, setSample] = useState<string>(getString());

  return <PagePropsContext.Provider value={pageProps}>{children}</PagePropsContext.Provider>;
};
...
```

What I'd like, for something like an auth context, is for `_app.tsx`'s `getInitialProps` to request the initial user object server side on page load, supply it to the context from the props, and not have the app re-request the initial user object unnecessarily on every page transition. I could do that if I could prevent `getInitialProps` from running on page transitions. Is there a way to prevent `getInitialProps` from running on those page transitions? Or a more idiomatic way to do what we're aiming for? (Ideally we'd prefer to avoid `getInitialProps` entirely, but the same issue remains with `getServerSideProps`, how to make it invoke only on a fresh page load.)

Comment: Can you use a cookie for this?

Comment: ... I suppose, but the app could unmount and be reloaded without the browser closing. And I'm curious if there is a more react/next-ish way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By closely examining the `context` object in both `getInitialProps` and `getServerSideProps`, I've noticed one element that appears to reliably indicate the difference between a client-side page transition and a fresh page load: `context.req.url` always seems to start with `/_next/data` for a client-side page transition - even if the code itself (`getInitialProps` or `getServerSideProps`) is being run on the server side.

So we are trying out code that looks like:

```
if (!req || (req.url && req.url.startsWith('/_next/data'))) {
  // return early
}
...
```

I'm not certain if this is reliable or "supported" for future releases, so I've also opened a feature request here:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/19459

Comment: This is the right answer. You can also try to differentiate client and server by some of `req.headers`, like `'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate'`, but `url` seems more reliable even though it is still quite hacky.

Answer (score 2):

`getInitialProps` is only called server-side on the first load. During page transitions, `getInitialProps` in only called browser-side, whereas `getServerSideProps` will be called server-side on first load and during all transitions.

If you only want to fetch data server-side during the first-load, you should use `getInitialProps` only, like this:

```
MyPage.getInitialProps = async () => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    return {} // browser-side, fetch data directly in component
  }

  console.log('server-side !');
  const data = {} // fetch your data
  return { data }
};
```

You can then set your context state with the received props.

```
const PagePropsProvider: React.FC<IProps> = ({ pageProps, children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
    if (pageProps.data) {
      setState(pageProps.data)
    }
  }, [pageProps.data])
  return <PagePropsContext.Provider value={state}>{children}</PagePropsContext.Provider>;
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option for us, as several of our pages really do require `getServerSideProps`. When navigating to a page that has `getServerSideProps`, the `getInitialProps` from `_app.js` is called server-side.

Comment: Ok, I understand the problem. Out of curiosity, what is it that you can achieve with `getServerSideProps` that you can't achieve with `getInitialProps` ?

Comment: You're right... if we changed all pages to use `getInitialProps` instead of `getServerSideProps`, the problem would go away. The main resistance there is just that it's clear NextJS is moving away from `getInitialProps`, so it feels like a step backwards. The other benefit is in saving on bundle size since the contents of `getServerSideProps` don't get delivered to the client. Those aren't dealbreakers so it might be the direction we go if we don't find a better solution. I have suggested an alternate solution to the nextJS team though, which I'll mention in a different answer.